# NHibernate mapping of one class containing 2 references to the same entity

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a person class, then have a family class where I have a property Father and a property Mother of type Person.

I have a database table for Person and a Family table containing FamilyId, FatherId, MotherId where FatherId and MotherId is foreign keys for PersonId in Person table.

How would you go about to map this in NHibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This mapping expresses your tables.

```
public class Family
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Mother { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Father { get; set; }
}

<class name="Family">
    <id name="Id" column="FamilyId">
        <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="Mother" column="MotherId" />
    <many-to-one name="Father" column="FatherId" />
</class>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have good reasons for your design in the given context.

In theory, you're often better off with a more loosely coupled, flexible, role-based design.

By that I mean that a person is a «Party», and father and mother are «Role»s that a person can play (other roles for a «Party» might be employee, customer, friend, and so forth).

I personally like Peter Coad's DNC pattern in order to solve this particular design problem. An article can be found here: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/32543

Some years ago, I worked on a large ERP system where I introduced DNC in a C# + NHibernate context, so I know it works in practice as well ;-)

For an in-depth analysis of the role pattern/archetype, have a look at the book [Enterprise patterns and MDA: building better software with archetype patterns and UML](http://books.google.com/books?id=NefmonGgEEMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=archetypes+neustadt&ei=QVeOS8yTDoiKyQS9z5XWAg&cd=1#v=onepage&q=&f=false).

There's also ongoing research in order to solve this problem at the language level, rather than using a pattern, called DCI: http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_visionP.html